# Print Layout Changes

Tags: jquery, html, printing

I just wanna ask, why does my HTML layout and Print Layout is not the same.

Here's my HTML Layout . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCVkn.png)

And Here's my Print Layout . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z5xr.png)

But when I change the scale from 100 to 70 it adjusts in its original HTML layout .. Why does this happened ??

here's my code in print trigger..

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
   $('#print').on('click', function(e)  {
        $("#printArea").printMe({ "path": ["{{ asset('template/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css') }}","{{ asset('template/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"] });
   }); 
});
```

I am using printme jquery plugin by the way ..

Thanks for all your answers ..

Comment: Because you're passing in the Bootstrap grid as a CSS file, which has breakpoints at certain widths.

Comment: i am using the bootstrap grid thats why i included the bootstrap.css ..

Comment: Scale directly correlates to DPI, which correlates to number of pixels on the screen. When you adjust the scale, Bootstrap thinks there are now less pixels for the width, and triggers its media query which shifts the elements around the page.

Comment: Ive tried removing the bootstrap-grid.css and instead using the default template grid .. and still the same result ..